# Select MAX from multiple Tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have four tables, and each table has a date column in it. I am trying to get MAX date of these four date columns.

```
    DateTime maxDate = ((from stockIn in db.StockIns select stockIn.StockInDate)
.Union(from stockOut in db.StockOuts select stockOut.StockOutDate)
.Union(from stockC in db.StockClearances select stockC.StockClearanceDate)
.Union(from stockR in db.StockRejections select stockR.StockRejectionDate))
.Max().Value;
```

Is this the simplest way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's the way your data is stored, that's pretty much as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `UNION` for this problem as the query may have poor performance. Union of 4 tables and then sorting (to get the Max) might be really slow with big tables.

Either get 4 MaxDates from 4 queries and find max of them in the application or use 4 subqueries to get these 4 MaxDates and then either a (SQL syntax) `CASE WHEN` or a `UNION` of these results (which would be only 4 rows) and a `MAX()`.

No idea how to translate either from SQL to `Linq-to-sql` ...

Comment: Just replacing `.Union` with `.Concat` should alleviate any performance concerns, as this translates to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @ypercube: But it will be more tedious on code side and more null value comparisons. That is, imagine if two columns gives null as MAX value, so in that case these values must not be added to final list from which we again want the MAX.

Comment: @Tim Rogers: But Concat function, concates the date string. Then how would we be able to find MAX on concated values ??

Comment: @Marshal [Queryable.Concat<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351755.aspx) method.

Comment: @Marshal: I didn't say it would be easier or simpler. Just gave another approach. Would you rather find your query works fine and then when the tables grow, it just takes ages to run?

Comment: And `MAX()` does not take NULL values into account. It just skips them.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, you are right, `UNION ALL` would probably be much better than `UNION` in this senario.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have your Stock all stored in one table, with linkages to other tables that say whether its In, Out, Clearance or Rejections.  Then you could simply do a MAX on the one table.